# Chart not clearing properly c#

Tags: c#, charts

When the GetValue button is pressed the chart behaves as expected, but when the ClearChart button is pressed the chart clears, but the numbers on the X axis are decimals e.g 1.99999999,2.99999999. It seems the X axis is not being reset as the scroll bar at the bottom does not keep to the right after the chart is cleared. How to I get this chart to clear and start off exactly like it does at the start of the program? here is my code.

```
int i;
Random rnd = new Random();

private void Chart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Chart1.Series.Add("Temp");
Chart1.Series["Temp"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
Chart1.Series["Temp"].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
}

private void GetValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0, 20);
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 20;

Chart1.Series["Temp"].Points.AddXY(i, rnd.Next(1, 10));
i++;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = Chart1.Series["Temp"].Points.Count - Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.Size;
}

private void ClearChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Chart1.Series["Temp"].Points.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was not resetting int i, always the simple things.

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing the points of the chart.

Add the following to the clear handler:

```
Chart1.Series["Temp"].Points.Clear();
```

Comment: Glad the problem is solved! 
Try keeping the original unedited code as first posted in your question for reference purposes.
Comments can always be added as your code is updated for testing from your side